# Looking for a solution to add numeric and float elements stored in list format in one of the columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

```
| Index    | col1           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 0        | [0,0]          |
| 2        | [7.9, 11.06]   |  
| 3        | [0.9, 4]       |
| 4        | NAN            |
```

I have data similar to like this.I want to add elements of the list and store it in other column say total using loop such that output looks like this:

```
| Index    | col1           |Total    |
| -------- | -------------- | --------|        
| 0        | [0,0]          |0        |
| 2        | [7.9, 11.06]   |18.9     |  
| 3        | [0.9, 4]       |4.9      |
| 4        | NAN            |NAN      |
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `na_action` parameter in map should work as well:

```
df['Total'] = df['col1'].map(sum,na_action='ignore')
```

Comment: This solution also  worked for the problem I was facing . Easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` with a `lambda` to sum the lists or return `np.NA` if the values are not a list:

```
df['Total'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: sum(x) if isinstance(x, list) else pd.NA)
```

I tried with `df.fillna([])`, but lists are not a valid parameters of fillna.

Edit: consider using awkward arrays instead of lists: https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you !! It worked I  tried with pd.NAN and using loops  but that didn't work out.